# Any way to add custom properties to the file properties grid in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, extensibility

In Visual Studio (specifically, 2008 and 2010), when you invoke the View.PropertiesWindow command (default key, F4) in a C# project, you get a property grid with a standard set of properties that apply to all project items.

Is there any way to customize that list of properties? Specifically, I'd like to associate additional information with project items which I later access via a Visual Studio extension (e.g. a custom tool).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do I see 2 exactly same question? Can you double check?

Comment: Hm, odd, SO listed me as signed in but prompted me when posting, apparently this somehow lead to a duplicate posting. I've deleted the other one, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm trying to do the same thing now (but for 2013) any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just answered this tonight. You can try to follow my code which should be pretty straight-forward. Let me know how it goes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699359/how-do-you-create-a-simple-automation-extender-for-visual-studio-with-uitypeedit/32700681#32700681. I didn't notice this post until now. However, my post also addresses setting up a custom UITypeEditor for value selection.