# Register Visual Studio property extender for C# project references

Tags: visual-studio, ide, extensibility

Using the following answer I was able to add custom properties to C# files in a project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700681/638244.

Now I would like to do the same for references that are added to the C# project, but which CatID do I need to provide to the ObjectExtenders.RegisterExtenderProvider() method to achieve this?
I've already tried the following, but the CanExtend() and GetExtender() methods were never called.

- VSConstants.CATID.VCReferences_string
- VSConstants.CATID.VCAssemblyReferenceNode_string
- VSConstants.CATID.VCProjectReferenceNode_string

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The correct catID to use to extend references is "VSLangProj.PrjBrowseObjectCATID.prjCATIDCSharpReferenceBrowseObject".